# stop official twitter widget escaping outside my divs border

Tags: html, css, twitter

so here http://www.prxa.info/ I am using on the right the official twitter widget. Currently it is using a set width.

I am wandering if there is a way to get it to expand to the width of the div it is contained it to expand and shrink as it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
#twitter-widget-0 { 
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]